# Hello world returns errors in Visual C++(MFC) using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just created a MFC application from Visual Studio.NET 2012.

Didn't write a scratch, but build.

And it returns several error like

```
error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\driverspecs.h    350
error C2065: '__In_impl_' : undeclared identifier   c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\driverspecs.h    350
IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h  369
```

I don't know where to start to fix this problem.

Here is the screen capture.

[image]

The oly thing I am suspicious about is that I am using Visual Studio.NET 2005, 2010 and 2012 in one computer.

Anyone has any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

__In_impl_ is a SAL annotation that used to told compiler infomation about params. i am not such familiar with visual studio, try to check SAL options.

Answer (score 0):

Project Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include

====

Each VisualStudio version contains a sal.h file:

VS2010 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sal.h

VS2012 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\sal.h

VS2010's sal.h not define __In_impl_ .